# how do I read every word of every line from a text file and create a result output file that has 1 word per line?

Tags: batch-file

[batch script] how do I read every word of every line from a text file and create a result output file that has 1 word per line from the source text file?

Some of the examples that I have found here provide reading a full line and printing it. Others read for a specific text within the lines of a text file.  And in trying those examples, they work for my file - and I am able to read say the first word of every line.  But I am unable to expand it to the output I am looking for.

Here is an example source file "inputFile1.txt":

```
0.2000 1.67 12.00 2.00 0.00 0 0 Uniax (m)
ASCII
9.007729E-02 -1.628449E-01 4.201064E-02 6.213378E-02 -3.099536E-01 -2.033296E-01 6.332591E-02 -7.577174E-02 -1.100574E-01
```

Desired output file:

```
0.2000 
1.67 
12.00 
2.00 
0.00 
0 
0 
Uniax 
(m)
ASCII
9.007729E-02 
-1.628449E-01 
4.201064E-02 
6.213378E-02 
-3.099536E-01 
-2.033296E-01 
6.332591E-02 
-7.577174E-02 
-1.100574E-01
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

```
type "file.txt"|repl " " "\r\n" x >"file2.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

Someyhing like this :

Edit :

```
@echo off&cls
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type "inputfile.txt"') do for %%b in (%%a) do echo %%b
pause
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  Unfortunately, the result file is displaying only the first word of every line from the input file when I tried your suggestion:  for /f "delims= " %%a in ('type "C:\temp\inputFile.txt" ') do for %%b in (%%a) do echo %%b >>Output.txt

Comment: No, this code dysplay every word of every line... I tested it with your example.

Comment: My apologies, I had a space in my "delims= ".  After changing that to "delims=" - it stopped after ASCII and did not print the remainder.

Comment: Ok see my edit and test it like that, it works for me... If it work on the screen then redirect it on your output file.

Comment: Is there a limit on the no# of words in the third line?  My screen shot only captured about 9 words in the third line, but the file has over 1000 words in the third line.  it appears to have stopped after reaching a limit.  Any further thoughts/comments?  Once again thank you for your quick response and ideas.

Comment: Thank you Sachadee for your time and solution.  I think found the hurdle, not sure if I can cross it though.

Comment: Thank you Sachadee for your time and solution.  we think we found the hurdle, not sure if we can cross it though.  There appears to be limit of 8192 characters per line.  After we split my third line into 2 pieces (making my input file for this example as 4 lines), the above code snippet worked perfectly.  So, we need to find a way to overcome the limitation.